# Can you change Windows Mobile Device Centre to use a different network from 192.168.55.0/24 for debugging the compact framework?

Tags: compact-framework, activesync, wmdc

I have a piece of software I have written that  talks to a web service over it's Wifi connection on a Casio WinCE handheld.

Unfortunately the Wifi network and the network created by WMDC (or ActiveSync) to host the debugger connection clash, they are both 192.168.55.0/24. So I can't have them both connected at the same time.

Does anybody know if you can reconfigure WMDC to use a different address range?
I've hunted through the registry but can't see anything obvious, and Google is not turning up anything useful.

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the development PC on teh same network as the WiFi connection?  If so, I'd abandon ActiveSync/WMDC altogetehr and just [use ethernet debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228708%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) over the same connection that it's using for the web service calls.

Comment: That was indeed what I used in the end, but I'm not allowed to answer my own questions within 8 hours or something.

However I used [this page here](http://community.opennetcf.com/articles/cf/archive/2007/08/31/debugging-without-activesync.aspx) by some bloke called Chris... ;)